# how to refresh display only items values based on list of values without refreshing the page in apex?"

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a page with 5 regions
the first region conssist of 1 page item from type lov
the second and forth consist of interactive report that display data based on the change of lov.
the third region is static content with 5 display only items ,the source of them is sql query based on the change of lov.
these items can't get the data in every change of lov without refreshing the page
the last region is pie chart .
all region are refreshing and display the correct data based the lov value except the display only items.

i tried to use dynamic actin to refresh the region and to refresh the every item but no refresh without refreshing the page.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Please extract only the relevant information from your question - I think the question is: how do I refresh a static region that displays page items without refreshing the page. Is that correct ? It would be very helpful if you created a test case based on the emp/dept sample dataset showcasing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes it correct
how do I refresh a static region that displays page items without refreshing the page

Comment: Please provide more info in your question. Explain in detail how to create the static region so I can reproduce...

Comment: I have been created a region of type static content then created the 5 page item in the region and did there source

Answer (score 0):

A static region does not support the refresh action, it is meant to show html that is defined at page rendering. For displaying content that supports refresh, use the region type "Dynamic Content". The built-in help has a good example of sample code that can be used.

- Create a region of type "Dynamic Content"
- Set "Page Items to Submit" to all the page items that need refreshing
- Create a dynamic action on change of the select list with

  - a true action of type "Set Value" *for each page item that needs to be changed*
  - a true action of type refresh for the region of type "Dynamic Content".

--- update ---

Page items cannot be "refreshed" - their values can be set by source attribute, default value attribute, computation or page processes. Those are all pre-rendering actions in APEX, they cannot be "redone" once the page is rendered. To change the value of a page item programmatically after the page is rendered, use a dynamic action of type "Set Value".